# How to search for the question "what is the definition of =?"

Tags: support, search

It seems that the search engines (whether SE or Google) don't register the "=" punctuation mark, so it is not easy to find this Q.

How I found it was by searching "definition of score:10" (because I remembered it had a score of at least 10), then going through the list of search results (it was third on [the list](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=definition%20of%20score:10)).

But is there an easier way?

(By the way the question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318297/what-is-the-definition-of).)

Comment: [`title:definition score:10`](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Adefinition+score%3A10) results in only 57 hits. Also, [`title:definition "$=$"`](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Adefinition+%22%24%3D%24%22) results in 6 hits.  (Note that [`title:definition "="`](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Adefinition+%22%3D%22) gives considerably more hits.)